# XMLHttpRequest alters text in UTF-8

Tags: javascript, ajax, unicode, xmlhttprequest

While processing a huge XML client-side, got stuck with the following issue: some unicode characters are replaced with unreadable sequences, so server cannot parse that XML. Testing like this:

```
var text = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlNode);
console.log(text);
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', config.saveUrl, true);
req.overrideMimeType("application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
req.send(text);
```

Logging still shows the correct string:

```
<Language Self="Language/$ID/Czech" Name="$ID/Czech" SingleQuotes="‚‘" DoubleQuotes="„“" PrimaryLanguageName="$ID/Czech" SublanguageName="$ID/" Id="266" HyphenationVendor="Hunspell" SpellingVendor="Hunspell" />
```

While in the request (Chrome dev tools) and at server side it appears modified like this:

```
<Language Self="Language/$ID/Czech" Name="$ID/Czech" SingleQuotes="â€šâ€˜" DoubleQuotes="â€žâ€œ" PrimaryLanguageName="$ID/Czech" SublanguageName="$ID/" Id="266" HyphenationVendor="Hunspell" SpellingVendor="Hunspell" />
```

Original encoding of the XML file is UTF-8, too. Absolutely the same behavior when using jQuery.

Comment: Can you show us how you're constructing the XML?

Comment: the string you see in Chrome dev tools would almost certainly be the one you said is correct if you looked at it in UTF-8. Those 3-byte sequences starting with `â` almost certainly are the `‚‘` etc. characters. They appear as 3-character sequences because you are looking at them in a single-byte encoding, like ISO-8859-15

Comment: You really need to look at what the string actually is, not just what it's displayed as. What are the integral values in the string where `â€šâ€˜` is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that overrideMimeType use uppercase "UTF-8" or lowercase "utf-8"
2. Make sure that string before javascript calculation was in utf-8 (check page charset)
3. Use escape/encodeURIComponent/decodeURIComponent before send it to server and unescape it on server
4. Try application/x-www-form-urlencoded ans send xml like plain text

P.S. Modified string is in ISO-8859-15

Answer (score 0):

It seems to do so.

I have here data json parameter that includes a string "Lääke" (finnish word), that i sent to server via ajax.

This did NOT work, server app did not receive 'ää' but '??':

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    status = this.responseText;
    if (status === "OK") {
        window.location.assign("ackok.html");
    }
    else {
        window.location.assign("ackerror.html");
    }
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "ProcessOrderServlet?Action=new&Customer="+data, true);    
xhttp.send();
```

This did work, server received 'ää':

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    status = this.responseText;
    if (status === "OK") {
        window.location.assign("ackok.html");
    }
    else {
        //orderStatusElement[0].innerHTML = "<b>Palvelimella jokin meni vikaan. Yritä myöhemmin uudelleen </b>";
        window.location.assign("ackerror.html");
    }
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "ProcessOrderServlet?Action=new&Customer="+data, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
xhttp.send();
```